# Java serializable object to byte array to file has garbage at the beginning of the file

Tags: java, serialization, arrays

I can save a serializable Java object to file in the following way:

```
Object mySerializableObj;

// assign value to mySerializableObj

try 
{
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(strFile1ToWritePath));
    writer.write(part.toString());
    return error;
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{}
```

However I need to send that object as a byte array instead. However when I try to do:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = null;
try 
{
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
    out.writeObject(mySerializableObj);
    byte[] objBytes = bos.toByteArray();
    FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream(strFile2ToWritePath);
    fos2.write(objBytes);
    fos2.close(); 
} 
catch (Exception ex){}
```

I get some binary junk prepended if I compare the two resulting files. Otherwise they are the same.

The binary pre-pended is AC ED 00 05 7C 00 00 00 00 00 13 34 FB
and I can see from the JavaWorld article "The Java serialization algorithm revealed" at http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html
That this is "functions as designed".

Is there a way to avoid this?

Thank you,
Bert

Comment: Why? How are you planning to deserialize the byte array without the stream header?

Comment: What do you mean, "need to send that object as a byte array"?  You are sending it as a byte array, just in a particular encoding.  Files are sequences of bytes.  `ObjectOutputStream` does serialization magic which it sounds like you don't want.

Answer (score -1):

Try to override `writeStreamHeader()` of `ObjectOutputStream`

like

```
 public class MyObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {
      public MyObjectOutputStream (OutputStream out) throws IOException {
         super(out);
      }
      @Override
      protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {

      }
 }
```

Comment: And then what? You've got a useless piece of data.